# I am trying to a write an update query for a table based on the value of an attribute in another table.

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

thus far I have

```
UPDATE dbo.Demographics
SET MAIL_MAG = 0
Inner Join dbo.Name
On Demographics.ID=dbo.Name.ID
Where dbo.Name STATUS = 'CON'
```

What I am unsure is if I have to have the inner join and if I am doing it correctly. I know that the attribute in both tables is ID.

Also do I have to use "dbo."

Answer (score 3):

This is the syntax for updating a table with a `JOIN` in SQL Server.

You also should use aliases for tables. 
For the `Demographics` table I have used `d`, for the `Name` table I have used `n`.

You do not need to use `dbo` in your update statement.

```
UPDATE d
SET d.MAIL_MAG = 0
FROM Demographics d 
INNER JOIN Name n On n.ID = d.ID
WHERE 
n.STATUS = 'CON'
```

Comment: You don't seem to have aliased the table

Comment: @Donal...little edit: need to put the "d" after Demographics in the FROM line.

Comment: I'll give it a try. just curious, but are there any alternatives to this syntax?

Comment: @user2884379 No, in SQL Server this is the syntax. Other RDBMS have slightly different syntax.